# c++ -- How to break out of a for loop on a different thread (non-blocking I/O related)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, nonblocking

I currently have the following code:

```
void isItDone() {
  char ans;
  while(true) {
    std::cout << "done? (y/n) ";
    std::cin >> ans;
    if(ans == 'y') break;
  }
}

int main() {
  //some interactive plotting
  ...
  //

  std::thread t(isItDone);
  t.join();

  //get info from interaction with plot
  ...
  //
  return 0;
}
```

There are three things I want to do:

1. Draw some plots and make some graphical cuts out of them
2. Confirm that cuts are made
3. Retrieve and save the cuts

The problem that I have at the moment is that step 2 does not allow for plots to be drawn.

Naively, I expected the above code to first draw the plot, then, on a different thread keep asking if the user is done. Once step 2 is done (i.e. cuts are made), go back to the original thread and finish the main function.

However, what I found is that even though std::cin is in a different thread, it is still blocking the plot drawing process. So, at the moment, no plots are drawn, and I have to break out of step 2 first before anything else can happen.

Please let me know if there is a way to fix this, or if I should approach this differently.

Comment: This example might be a bit too minimal.  What are your other threads doing?  Where are they created?

Comment: `std::atomic<bool>`?

Comment: @StephenNewell I am not explicitly defining any other threads, so I think there should only be one other thread that runs the main function.

Comment: @Eljay I haven't used ```std::atomic``` before. I'm not sure how it applies to my case, but I will look into it.

Comment: Your main thread is blocked in `t.join()` until `isItDone` returns and the worker thread terminates. It's kinda pointless to create a thread and then join it right away; nothing in fact runs in parallel in this program.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I see. Sorry, I'm still pretty new to this multithreading business. What would be the correct way to make sure things run in parallel?

Comment: Bad user experience to ask "Done? (Y/N)" and then if I enter "N" it just asks again.    (And why would I do that?  Why wouldn't I just do _nothing_, until I'm ready to enter Y?) 
Perhaps just "Press any key to exit" is a better experience.

Comment: To communicate a simple bit of information between two threads, use (a) a `std::condition_variable` combined with a `std::mutex` in case you want a (somewhat) rigorously defined synchronization behavior with passive waiting or (b) `std::atomic<bool>` if your consistency expectations are (far) more relaxed and busy waiting is not a concern (e.g. when both communicating sides are “fast”, i.e. independent of I/O and user input and the expected costs / durations of busy waiting are smaller than those of context switches plus compare-and-swaps).